# Error in setting up genesis transactions -- what am I doing wrong?

Tags: cosmos-sdk

I'm trying to go through the "Running a node" tutorial here: https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/master/docs/run-node/run-node.md

I seem to have some issue though, the genesis transactions don't manage to set up a validator, so the validator set is empty and the app stops. Am I missing something?

I'm running `script.sh` and getting error message in `error.log`

`simd version`: `goz-phase-1-1119-g8572a84eb`

`script.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

PATH=build:$PATH

MONIKER=foobar

simd init $MONIKER --chain-id my-test-chain

simd keys add my_validator --keyring-backend test

# Put the generated address in a variable for later use.
MY_VALIDATOR_ADDRESS=$(simd keys show my_validator -a --keyring-backend test)

simd add-genesis-account $MY_VALIDATOR_ADDRESS 100000000stake

# Create a gentx.
simd gentx my_validator 100000stake --chain-id my-test-chain --keyring-backend test

# Add the gentx to the genesis file.
simd collect-gentxs

simd start
```

`error.log`:

```
5:09PM INF starting ABCI with Tendermint
5:09PM INF Starting multiAppConn service impl={"Logger":{}} module=proxy
5:09PM INF Starting localClient service connection=query impl="marshaling error: json: unsupported type: abcicli.Callback" module=abci-client
5:09PM INF Starting localClient service connection=snapshot impl="marshaling error: json: unsupported type: abcicli.Callback" module=abci-client
5:09PM INF Starting localClient service connection=mempool impl="marshaling error: json: unsupported type: abcicli.Callback" module=abci-client
5:09PM INF Starting localClient service connection=consensus impl="marshaling error: json: unsupported type: abcicli.Callback" module=abci-client
5:09PM INF Starting EventBus service impl={"Logger":{}} module=events
5:09PM INF Starting PubSub service impl={"Logger":{}} module=pubsub
5:09PM INF Starting IndexerService service impl={"Logger":{}} module=txindex
5:09PM INF ABCI Handshake App Info hash= height=0 module=consensus protocol-version=0 software-version=
5:09PM INF ABCI Replay Blocks appHeight=0 module=consensus stateHeight=0 storeHeight=0
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=0/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=1/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=2/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=3/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=4/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=5/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=6/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=7/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=8/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=9/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserting crisis invariants inv=10/11 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF asserted all invariants duration=0.844065 height=0 module=x/crisis
5:09PM INF created new capability module=ibc name=ports/transfer
5:09PM INF port binded module=x/ibc/port port=transfer
5:09PM INF claimed capability capability=1 module=transfer name=ports/transfer
Error: error during handshake: error on replay: validator set is nil in genesis and still empty after InitChain
Usage:
  simd start [flags]

Flags:
      --abci string                                     specify abci transport (socket | grpc) (default "socket")
... [other usage info]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried it myself and saw the same error but was able to fix it by increasing the amount of stake in the `simd gentx` command to `100000000stake`. It works now as follows:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
set -eu

PATH=build:$PATH

MONIKER=foobar

simd init $MONIKER --chain-id my-test-chain

simd keys add my_validator --keyring-backend test

# Put the generated address in a variable for later use.
MY_VALIDATOR_ADDRESS=$(simd keys show my_validator -a --keyring-backend test)

simd add-genesis-account $MY_VALIDATOR_ADDRESS 100000000stake

# Create a gentx.
simd gentx my_validator 100000000stake --chain-id my-test-chain --keyring-backend test

# Add the gentx to the genesis file.
simd collect-gentxs

# simd start
```

Where did you get the `script.sh` file from? I didn't see it inside of https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk/blob/master/docs/run-node/run-node.md

Comment: It's the sequence of commands in the `run-node.md` document. The two keygen steps (`simd keys add ...` and `MY_VALIDATOR_ADDRESS=...`) are from the previous step on key generation.

Reading through the document, these are simply the steps I've understood it is asking me to take, in this order, so I made it a script for easy replication.

The `build` directory is the default location of `simd`, which is why it's added to the path. If someone builds elsewhere, it won't work.

Comment: The `min_deposit` param has probably changed. Multiplying all values by 1000 is probably a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from okwme is correct. But the initial balance (set with `simd add-genesis-account`) should also be increased if you want to play around more with that account. In the tutorial, later that account sends some `stake` to another account. But with the above script, the full amount in `$MY_VALIDATOR_ADDRESS` is delegated, so none can be sent.